# os.popen().read() hangs until I type "exit" in the console

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
import platform
import socket
import webbrowser
import psutil
from subprocess import check_output
import re
import urllib.request
import winreg as reg
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time
import sys
import subprocess

outfile = open('platform.txt', "w")

hardwareList = ["Platform: " + platform.system()]

hardwareList.append("Operating System: " + platform.platform())

info = os.popen('cmd /k systeminfo | find "Original Install Date"').read()
stripInfo = info.replace('Original Install Date:     ','')
hardwareList.append("OS Installation Date: " + stripInfo.strip())


hardwareList.append("Processor: " + platform.processor())

hardwareList.append("Qty Physical CPU's: %s " % psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))

hardwareList.append("Qty Logical CPU's: %s" % psutil.cpu_count(logical=True))

hardwareList.append("Qty Cores: %s" % (psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)/psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)))

memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
hardwareList.append("RAM: " + str("{:3.2f}".format(memory[0]/1024/1024/1024)))

diskUsage = psutil.disk_usage('C:/')
total = "{:4.2f}".format((diskUsage[0]/1024/1024/1024))
avail = "{:4.2f}".format((diskUsage[2]/1024/1024/1024))
used = "{:4.2f}".format((diskUsage[1]/1024/1024/1024))

hardwareList.append("Total Capacity: %s " % total + "MB")

hardwareList.append("Total Free: %s " % avail + "MB")

hardwareList.append("Total Used: %s " % used + "MB")

clocksp = str(check_output("wmic cpu get MaxClockSpeed"))
clocksp1 = re.findall(r'\d+',clocksp)
clocksp2 = (float(clocksp1[0])/1000)
hardwareList.append("Clockspeed: %s" % clocksp2 + " GHz")

hardwareList.append("Network Data:")

hardwareList.append("HostName: " + socket.gethostname())

hardwareList.append("FQDN: " + socket.getfqdn())

hardwareList.append("IP Address: " + socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))

dbTypes = ['MongoDB','MSSQLSERVER','MySQL','postgresql-x64-9.5']
for db in dbTypes:
    try:
        dbInfo = psutil.win_service_get(db).as_dict()        
        hardwareList.append("Database Name: " + dbInfo['display_name'] + ", status=" + dbInfo['status'])
    except:
        search = dbInfo['display_name'].find(db)
        if search != -1:
            hardwareList.append(search)
        else:
            hardwareList.append("Database Name: " + db + ", status=Not installed")

softwareList = []
for dir in os.listdir("C:\Program Files"):
    if os.path.isdir("C:\Program Files"+"\\"+dir):        
        hardwareList.append("Software: " + dir)

for ins in hardwareList:
    outfile.write(str(ins) + "\r\n")

outfile.close()
```

So what's happening here is that the code is hanging up and failing to complete (it produces a blank text file with no data called 'platform.txt') until I type 'exit' in the console.  I want this to run without human intervention and I don't know python well enough to figure out how to overcome this problem.
Help me make it run without having to type "exit" in the console.

Note: I've tried subprocess, but got lost in all the difficult to read manual documentation, and other solutions provided on StackOverflow didn't do what I wanted it to do.
I believe it is failing at this line:
    info = os.popen('cmd /k systeminfo | find "Original Install Date"').read()
But can't be sure.

I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: "But can't be sure." Why not? Put a bunch of print statements and find where it hangs.

Comment: I tried this...and it did not execute the print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/k` option to `cmd` means "Carries out the command specified by string but remains" - in other words, you are explicitly telling it to behave in this undesired manner.  Try `/c` instead - "Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates".

Comment: Worked!  So it wasn't Python that was tripping me up...it was CMD.  Thanks a lot for the quick response!